# Can we create two ng-view for a single application with different templates surrounding them?

Tags: angularjs, view

view for a single webapp , having different body surrounding them, i.e. headers and footers beside main template should be different. can we decide which template to choose on the basis of the URL in $stateProvider

Comment: You don't need several ng-views for that

Comment: Thanks , so from one ng view how can we change the surrounding template from url change?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using $stateProvider then you've to use ui-view directive not ng-view. ng-view is of ngRoute service where you need to use $routeProvider.

And yes you can have multiple ui-view on same page, it's called multiple named views. So let's say on index.html you can have it like:

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="mainsection"></div>
<div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

Now in your states deinition you can have like:

```
$stateProvider      
  .state('app', {        
    views: {        
      'header': { ... templates and/or controllers ... },   
      'mainsection': { ... templates and/or controllers ... },
      'footer': { ... templates and/or controllers ... } 
    }       
})
```

Now in above code for different views you can have different set of templates as well as controller (or Component in version >1.5) for particular state having particular url. So this way you can decide for each state (url) what to show for particular part of page like headers, footer, content. If some part is going to be constant then you can have nice re-usability feature by using using same templateUrl for those sates with that particular view name.

Checkout the documentation for more details: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/views#multiple-named-uiviews